# Scan error on column index converting string to a int

Tags: go

I use go-sql-driver, but when I run the code .

Errors comes with: 
sql: Scan error on column index 7: *converting string "1.461988e+06" to a int: strconv.ParseInt: parsing* "1.461988e+06": invalid syntax ,

Ooops ! what's the problem ? Int type can not assigned a value more than 1461988 ?

```
qs := `SELECT stepdistance,(CASE WHEN stepnumber>=10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),stepnumber,credit1,credit2,credit3,credit4,credit5,credit6,credit7,credit8,stepdaypass,timestamp,walkdate FROM wanbu_stat_activeuser_day_v1_n0 WHERE  activeid=?  AND userid=? AND  walkdate>=? AND walkdate<=? ORDER BY walkdate`
rows, err := db.Query(qs, arg.Aid, uid, start, end)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("49", err)
    return err
}
defer rows.Close()
var tmp Userdaytotalstat_s = Userdaytotalstat_s{}
var udts Userdaytotalstat_s = Userdaytotalstat_s{}
var snap Userdaytotalstat_s
var ifarrive = false

for rows.Next() {

    err := rows.Scan(&udts.Stepdistance, &udts.Stepdaywanbu, &udts.Stepnumber,&udts.Credit1, &udts.Credit2, &udts.Credit3, &udts.Credit4, &udts.Credit5, &udts.Credit6,&udts.Credit7, &udts.Credit8, &udts.Stepdaypass, &udts.Timestamp, &udts.Walkdate)

    if err != nil {

        fmt.Println("68", err)
        fmt.Println(qs, arg.Aid, uid, start, end)

        return err
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Exponent notations can not be parsed easily, since the value denoted by the string may well exceed anything a 64bit integer can hold, e.g "2.00+e1024". Furthermore, if you look closely, the string does *not* represent an integer. The *point* clearly denotes a floating *point* number.

So, you have to take some additional steps (<kbd>[Run on Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/skGaaNJzTc)</kbd>)

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"
import "math/big"

func main() {

    in := "1.461988e+06"
    fmt.Printf("Input:\t\t%v\t(Type: %[1]T)\n",in)

    // The value denoted by in is NOT an integer
    // It is a float with an exponent notation
    // It can not be directly parsed since with exponent notation
    // the integer value represented by in may well exceed anything
    // one of the int types can hold
    if e,err := strconv.ParseFloat("1.461988e+06",10); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n",err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Parsed:\t\t%#v\t(Type:%[1]T)\n",e)

        // Hence, we have to use the "big" package
        // And use it's facilities to retrieve the integer
        b := big.NewFloat(e)
        v,p := b.Int64()
        fmt.Printf("Integer:\t%v\t\t(Type:%[1]T,Precision: %v)",v,p)
    }

}
```

Comment: ,Thanks for detailed explanation.But I notice some strange thing. When I update the credit5 to the value less than 1000000,e.g 999999,the error won't comes out. The column credit5 type is double(11,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000'.Seems golang has it's special way parse float  to int ?

Comment: I'd guess it is the driver. But I honestly don't know why it gets parsed.